# Glossary with terms and definitions in English and Chinese

Tags: glossaries, babel, languages, glossaries-extra

I have two files, `main_EN.tex` and `main.CN.tex`, that hold the same content in English and Chinese respectively. They share the same preamble and the glossary file. The glossary is created with the `glossaries-extra` package. I am new to this package and feel a bit overwhelmed with the number of options and all the intricacies.

So I am not sure how to add to the glossary Chinese definitions for terms and acronyms, as well as Chinese translation for the terms.

Ideally, I would want to have something like this:

```
\newglossaryentry{charger}
{
    name-english={charger},
    name-chinese={充电器},
    description-english={A device for charging mobile phones},
    description-chinese={给手机充电的设备}
}

\newacronym{usb}{USB}
{
    translation-english={Universal Serial Bus},
    translation-chinese={通用串行总线}
}
```

Then I want to be able to pull definitions for a selected language.

[This thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/495323/how-to-store-and-use-multilingual-symbol-and-acronym-definitions) proposes a way, but I cannot make it work with Chinese, and it looks a bit complicated.

**Can you please suggest the best way to do it?**

So far, I have tried adding translations with the package `translations`. See the MWE code below or see the actual [MWE](https://www.overleaf.com/read/tcwwtpkbpbtn).

*my-preamble.sty*

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{my-preamble}


\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
% Import local copy of `babel-zh.ini`
\babelprovide[import]{chinese}
\usepackage{translations}
\DeclareLanguage{chinese}

% Allow Chinese typesetting
\usepackage{ctex}

\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries-extra}

\makeglossaries


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% Definitions for the translations package %%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%\DeclareTranslationFallback{charger}{charger}
\DeclareTranslation{English}{charger}{charger}
\DeclareTranslation{chinese}{charger}{充电器}

%\DeclareTranslationFallback{def-charger}{A device for charging mobile phones}
\DeclareTranslation{English}{def-charger}{A device for charging mobile phones}
\DeclareTranslation{chinese}{def-charger}{给手机充电的设备}

%\DeclareTranslationFallback{def-usb}{Universal Serial Bus}
\DeclareTranslation{English}{def-usb}{Universal Serial Bus}
\DeclareTranslation{chinese}{def-usb}{通用串行总线}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% Definitions for the glossaries-extra package %%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\newglossaryentry{charger}
{
    name={\GetTranslation{charger}},
    description={\GetTranslation{def-charger}}
}

\newacronym{usb}{USB}{\GetTranslation{def-usb}}
```

*main_EN.tex*

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{my-preamble}

\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{english}

\section*{In English}

The \gls{charger} has three \glsxtrfull{usb} ports.

\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

*main_CN.tex*

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{my-preamble}

\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{chinese}

\section*{在中文中}

\gls{charger}有三个 \glsxtrfull{usb} 端口

\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

Result

| English | Chinese |
| --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] |

As you can see, the sections *Glossary* and *Acronyms* show proper translations, but the term label is not replaced with the actual term in the body of the document. I also get multiple "Undefined Control Sequence" errors.

Any help will be very much appreciated!

---

**Edit:**

In a comment, *Venez* proposed an idea to use the `iflang` package. It works perfectly!

See the MWE code below or see the actual [MWE](https://www.overleaf.com/read/jnmschrzdhsb).

*my-preamble.sty*

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{my-preamble}


\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
% Import local copy of `babel-zh.ini`
\babelprovide[import]{chinese}
\usepackage{translations}
\DeclareLanguage{chinese}

\usepackage{iflang}

% Allow Chinese typesetting
\usepackage{ctex}

\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries-extra}

\makeglossaries
```

*glossary.tex*

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% Definitions for the glossaries-extra package %%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\newglossaryentry{charger}
{
    name={\IfLanguageName{english}
        {charger}
        {充电器}},
    description={\IfLanguageName{english}
        {A device for charging mobile phones}
        {给手机充电的设备}}
}
    
\newacronym{usb}{USB}
{
    \IfLanguageName{english}
        {Universal Serial Bus}
        {通用串行总线}
}
```

*main__EN.tex*

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{my-preamble}

\begin{document}

\selectlanguage{english}
\input{glossary}

\section*{In English}

The \gls{charger} has three \glsxtrfull{usb} ports.

{\let\clearpage\relax
    \printglossaries
}

\end{document}
```

*main__CN.tex*

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{my-preamble}

\begin{document}

\selectlanguage{chinese}
\input{glossary}

\section*{在中文中}

\gls{charger}有三个 \glsxtrfull{usb} 端口

{\let\clearpage\relax
    \printglossaries
}

\end{document}
```

Result

| English | Chinese |
| --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] |

Comment: I think you have multiple choices here. 1st: you declare your own fields with their commands (`\glsEN` VS`\glsCN`). 2nd: you use separate glossaries for each language with identical labels so you only have to activate the right one in your actually main file. However, that's not really maintenance-friendly from my POV. 3rd: within one glossary you distinguish between two types or categories. Here you need different labels for every entry (e.g. `en:charger` VS `cn:charger`). And there are more ... so in the end the question is what's most important for you: a simple glossary or a simple main?

Comment: @Venez Thank you for your suggestions! My priority is to keep the main files simple, so options 1 and 3 are not for me. I thought about having two separate glossaries (reluctant to go this way for maintenance issues as you pointed out) and would have to choose this option if there is no simple solution to keep the EN and CN definitions in the same glossary file.

Comment: One last idea came up my mind, because i used something similar ... you could try the `iflang` package (see [CTAN](https://ctan.org/pkg/iflang)) to maintain only one glossary, but access both language variations by the same label (e.g. `name={\IfLanguageName{english}{then}{else}}`).

Comment: @Venez Works like a charm with `iflang`! Suggest that you post your comment as an answer and I will upvote it. I can delete the edit in my question. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following a short discussion (see comments below original question) the answer was a use of the `iflang` package. So the code below is a reduced MWE.

@f-hollow You do not have to delete your edit, but i propose you add your original code as well. Therefore it should be easy to understand first the problem and then the solution.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{ctex} % allows chinese typesetting, but you must have a compatible OS-font 
\usepackage{iflang}
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries-extra}


\newglossaryentry{charger}
{
    name={\IfLanguageName{english}{charger}{充电器}},
    description={\IfLanguageName{english}{A device for charging mobile phones}{给手机充电的设备}}
}
\newacronym{usb}{USB}
{
    \IfLanguageName{english}{Universal Serial Bus}{通用串行总线}
}

\makeglossaries
\begin{document}
    \selectlanguage{english}
    \section*{In English}   
    The \gls{charger} has three \glsxtrfull{usb} ports.
    
    \printglossaries
\end{document}
```

Comment: Need to point out that the glossary definitions should be preceded by `\selectlanguage`, otherwise the compiler always chooses English. In its turn, \selectlanguage must be inside of the document environment. So the order is \begin{document} > \selectlanguage > glossary defs.